# How can I use dates as values in a pandas pivot_table instead of numerical data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I imported a small dataset with three columns, and created a dataframe:  Account Code, Process Step (Upload, Submission, queued, exported), and Status Change Date (i.e. 2020-02-20), and attempted to pivot the data so that Process Steps become columns, populated with the dates

```
import pandas as pd
dtypes = {0:'object',1:'int',2:'object',3:'object'}} #set datatypes so Python doesn't waste memory checking all of them

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/User1/Documents/Data/Sales Audit Log.txt', delimiter = "\t", 
dtype=dtypes) # import the data

df.pivot_table(index="Org Code", columns="Process Step", values="Status Change Date")
print(df)
```

However, I got the error ***"pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate"*** due to Status Change Date being type Object. I changed the datatype for my 4th column to datetime64:

```
dtypes = {0:'object',1:'int',2:'object', 3:'datetime64'} #set datatypes so Python doesn't waste memory checking all of them
```

But unfortunately, this didn't work either, and resulted in the error ***"TypeError: the dtype datetime64 is not supported for parsing, pass this column using parse_dates instead"***

I would like to know if there is a method of using date columns as values in a python pivot table. I was following the instructions of [this article](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) in order to understand how to pivot data. But all of the examples are of the values being actual numerical data, where I have data data.

Comment: Do you mean to be using `df.pivot(...)` here instead of `.pivot_table` ?

Comment: @JonClements I did try to use df.pivot(...) but it gave me an error that there are duplicates in the Account Code column, so I tried pivot_table to pivot on Account Code since it has duplicates, and i don't want any duplication. Objective is to pivot Process Step, and have no duplicate Account Codes with data spread across multiple rows

Comment: Are you able to provide some sample data?

Comment: @JonClements here's a sample of my data. It's saved as .txt tab delimited text file https://pastebin.com/xsJEAF1b

Comment: Are `Status` and `Change Date` two different columns? If so, try `df.pivot_table(index="Org Code", columns="Process Step", values=["Status", "Change Date"])`.